# Getting output from Python files when executed through C#

Tags: python, c#

Im calling Python script from a C# app to execute with the code below

```
string srCommandName = "customWhisper.py D:\Tas\Monitor\Stemme_226.m4a 41f850e7-455e-4f84-b1eb-a5cccea49046.txt"
ProcessStartInfo psInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(srCommandName);
psInfo.UseShellExecute= false;
psInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
using (Process process = Process.Start(psInfo))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
    {
        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        if (result=="")
        { }
    }
}
```

My Python code is:

```
try:   
  if len(sys.argv)==3:
    mediaPath = sys.argv[1] 
    textFilePath = sys.argv[2]
    model = whisper.load_model("tiny")
    isExist = os.path.exists(mediaPath)    
    if isExist:
        results = model.transcribe(mediaPath, language = "da")
        stab_segments = results['segments']
        text_file = open(textFilePath, "w",encoding="utf-8")
        for i in stab_segments:
           text_file.write(i["text"] + '\n')
        text_file.close()
        print(0)
    else:
        print(1)
  else:
    print(len(sys.argv))
except Exception as er:
    print(er)
```

The desired output from string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); should had been 0 (print 0) on success or one of the other prints. But its the srCommandName

Is there any way to get Python to return a value when called from C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the below method to call python script from c# and get the result from python standard output back as a string. The **FileName** property of **ProcessStartInfo** should point to the python interpreter to use - not the python script. The python script should be sent as first argument.

```
   private (string output, int exitCode) RunPythonScript(string pathToPythonFile, string args)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = @"C:\MyPathToPythonInterpreter\Scripts\python.exe";
        start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", pathToPythonFile, args);
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
        {
            process.WaitForExit();

            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return (result, process.ExitCode);
            }
        }
    }
```